# How do you add an `li` tag only data exists in an array in html/css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am brand new to HTML/CSS/Javascript fyi. So I have a list of items in html using an `ul` tag and multiple `li` tags. I don't understand how I am only able to add an li if there is data that exists.

For example: I am using firebase as my backend. Lets say we have a list saved to firebase called myList:

```
myList = ["dog", "cat", "pig"]
```

So right now if i was going to use this list I would need 3 `li` tags.

```
<ul>
  <li>dog</li>
  <li>cat</li>
  <li>pig</li>
</ul>
```

But lets say another user adds a 4th element called "cow". So now myList equals:

```
myList = ["dog", "cat", "pig", "cow"]
```

I only have 3 `li` tags so how do I now add a 4th one to my code so it will present cow in the list? I understand in other languages you could just use a for loop for however many data points there are in your list, but html doesn't have for loops so how do I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this example

```
var node = document.createElement("LI");      // Create a <li> node

var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");  // Create a text node

node.appendChild(textnode);                      // Append the text to <li>

document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);  // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
```